# Union of 2 tuples python

Tags: python, tuples, union

I have two tuples:

```
 a= ('girl', 'boy') 
 b= ('boy', 'sex')
```

How can I get the following in Python?

```
    c = ('girl','boy','sex')
```

In words, I want to get union of the two tuples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a set for this:

```
a = ('girl', 'boy') 
b = ('boy', 'sex')
c = tuple(set(a + b))
```

Comment: it gives me ('b','o','y', 'g','i','r','l','s','e','x')

Comment: @mary You must be doing something wrong. It works completely fine for me: `('boy', 'girl', 'sex')`. What exactly do you have in `a` and `b`?

Comment: I was asking about `a` and `b`. Are you executing exactly the three statements my answer contains? Just like I have it there?

Comment: yes.. in python shell is going ok. but when i m trying to run this in a python programm it gives me this.

Comment: @mary I have just tried it in a script and it works the same, as expected. You must be doing something with the result.

Comment: I have written this:
for a, b in itemset_pairs:
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(tuple(set(a+b)))

Comment: @mary What does `itemset_pairs` contain? What is printed with the `print(a)` and `print(b)`?

Comment: You realize that `for a, b in itemset_pairs` does not give you two tuples, but two elements from the first tuple and then two elements from the second one (and so on)

Comment: `tuple(set(itemset_pairs[0] + itemset_pairs[1]))` is what you want, in case you have your tuples in a list of two.

Comment: its giving me ( '(','b','o','y', 'g','i','r','l','s','e','x', ')' ) and i dont know why!!!

Comment: can you share what do you have in your itemset_pairs variable exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a set intersection, then convert back to `tuple`

```
>>> c = tuple(set(a).union(b))
>>> c
('boy', 'sex', 'girl')
```

Comment: it gives me ('b','o','y', 'g','i','r','l','s','e','x')

Comment: No it doesn't, try again

Comment: I would do something like this because this doesn't maintain order necessarily.

Comment: `lst = []; for i in a + b: if i not in lst: lst.append(i)`

Answer (score 2):

```
In [4]: tuple(set(a+b))
Out[4]: ('boy', 'girl', 'sex')
```

or alternatively if you want to preserve the order

```
n [32]: res=[]+list(a)

In [33]: res
Out[33]: ['girl', 'boy']

In [34]: tuple(res.append(i) for i in b if i not in res) #list comprehension can also be used.
Out[34]: (None,)

In [35]: res
Out[35]: ['girl', 'boy', 'sex']

In [36]: tuple(res)
Out[36]: ('girl', 'boy', 'sex')
```

Comment: And it doesn't necessarily maintain order.